# JTextArea cannot show Hashmap values

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jtextarea

I want to print my hashmap values from pointset to the text area, but it won't work.
If I change some other things to print with set text or append, it will work instead(sth like "hello").

If I change for (int: pointSet.keyValue()) to for (int i=0; i<5; i++), the textfield  comes back working and can print.

Whenever I try to print anything related to my HashMap (for example, pointSet.size()), the textarea won't show anything.

I've been checking with the hash map and it's okiedokie, as the console output can print out the things, only the text area doesn't.

Is there anyway to solve it? Thank you first for looking at this question

```
    static HashMap<Integer, Point> pointSet = new HashMap<>();

    static int totalPoint;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mainWindow window = new mainWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public mainWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        frame = new JFrame("Groof Simulator");
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(20, 20, 1550, 961);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // MAP INPUT
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        pnlInput = new JPanel();
        pnlInput.setBounds(0, 0, 362, 1067);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pnlInput);
        pnlInput.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        pnlInput.setLayout(null);

        JTextPane txtNoOfPoint = new JTextPane();
        txtNoOfPoint.setForeground(new Color(0, 191, 255));
        txtNoOfPoint.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        txtNoOfPoint.setFont(new Font("OCR A Extended", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        txtNoOfPoint.setLocation(12, 56);
        txtNoOfPoint.setSize(166, 22);
        pnlInput.add(txtNoOfPoint);
        txtNoOfPoint.setText("No. of Point ");

        // INPUT

        mdltotalPoint = new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 20, 1);
        spntotalPoint = new JSpinner(mdltotalPoint);
        spntotalPoint.setBounds(190, 56, 70, 22);
        pnlInput.add(spntotalPoint);

        mdlcolonyThreshold = new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 50, 1);
        spncolonyThreshold = new JSpinner(mdlcolonyThreshold);
        spncolonyThreshold.setBounds(190, 91, 70, 22);
        pnlInput.add(spncolonyThreshold);

        mdltotalKangaroo = new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 50, 1);
        spntotalKangaroo = new JSpinner(mdltotalKangaroo);
        spntotalKangaroo.setBounds(190, 126, 70, 22);
        pnlInput.add(spntotalKangaroo);

        JButton btnSetMap = new JButton("SET MAP");
        btnSetMap.setBounds(0, 161, 362, 25);
        pnlInput.add(btnSetMap);
        btnSetMap.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                totalPoint = (int) mdltotalPoint.getValue();
                pointGenerator(totalPoint);

            }
        });

        JButton btnGenerate = new JButton(" GENERATE !");
        pnlInput.add(btnGenerate);
        btnGenerate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pointPrinter();
                //txtOutput.setText("The size is " + kangarooSet.size());

            }
        });

        JPanel pnlDisplay = new JPanel();
        pnlDisplay.setBounds(362, 162, 1182, 764);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pnlDisplay);
        pnlDisplay.setLayout(null);

        txtOutput = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        txtOutput.setLineWrap(true);
        txtOutput.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        pnlDisplay.add(txtOutput);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtOutput);
        scrollPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 191, 255)));
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setBounds(12, 94, 377, 657);
        pnlDisplay.add(scrollPane);

    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // INITIALIZE FUNCTIONS
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static void pointGenerator(int n) {// CREATE HASHMAP TO STORE POINTS
        pointSet = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            pointSet.put(i, new Point(i));
            ArrayList<Path> pathList = new ArrayList<>();
            pointPathSet.put(pointSet.get(i), pathList);
        }
        System.out.println("The final point set size is : " + pointSet.size());
    }

    public static void pointPrinter() {// PRINT CURRENT CONDITION OF POINTS

        for (int i: pointSet.keySet()) {            
            System.out.println( "\nPOINT " + i);//Use to test in console
            System.out.println(pointSet.get(i).toString());//Use to test in console
            txtOutput.append("\nPOINT " + i);
            txtOutput.append(pointSet.get(i).toString());
        }           
    }
}
```

this is the update in case somebody faces the same problem as me. The solution: Use a static String to keep all messages to be print, and print that static String in the jtextarea. yeahhhhh

Comment: Why are you running an inner and outer loop, surely you can use `for(Map.Entry<Integer,Point> currentPoint : pointSet.entrySet())` and then print each point with `txtOutput.append("\Point " + currentPoint.getKey() + " " + currentPoint.getValue()`
Also, you have two variables defined as `i`

Comment: oops my mistake, one of the for() is another way I tried but forgot to close (but both of ways don't work). I've tried with this entry<Integer, Point> as well, and don't know why  the textarea still doesnt show anything

Comment: 1) class names should start with an upper case character. Learn by example and follow the conventions used in the JDK. 2) Don't use static variables. This indicates improper design. 3) don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. 4) Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html). The `TextDemo` example will show you how to better structure your code and how to use an ActionListener to update a text area. Modify the code for your actual requirements.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the map. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Hi, I checked out the text Demo but there's no append or setText in the sample code. I avoid changing too big like static and layout as this assignment due date is very close T T

Comment: *but there's no append or setText in the sample code* - yes there is. Did you actually download the source file and compile and test it?

Comment: Hey camickr, after checking the demo and change my code for many times, i finally figured out the important key: use static string to print in jtextarea  if the variables keep updating. Thank you !!